# Adaboost - update of weights

Tags: self-study, boosting, adaboost

i am self-studying AdaBoost - and reading the following useful article. http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/ag-ki/adaboost4.pdf . I am trying to understand, as per below, the following questions:

1) When we select and extract from the pool of classifiers, do we extract from a given pool of classifiers (e.g. an existing pool of the first 100 trees), or do we (as i presume) create the optimal classifier from scratch (e.g. a new tree with different splitting variables)?

2) i am failing to see step 3 (the update of weights) - why do we know that the new weights are the old weights multipled with $e^{a_m}$ in case of a hit?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1), yes on both counts.  You can view training a new classifier as selecting the best classifier from the "pool" defined as the range (i.e. the collection of all possible resultant classifiers) of the classification algorithm.

For 2), this re-weighting scheme is simply part of the definition of the adaboost algorithm.  A reasonable question is, of course, why this choice?  Reweighing in this way allows one to bound the training error with an exponentially decreasing function.  Here is Theorem 3.1 from [Boosting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262526034) by Schapire and Freund:

> Given the notation of algorithm 1.1 (adaboost) let $\lambda_t = \frac{1}{2} - e_t$, and let $D_1$ be any initial distribution over the training set.  Then the weighted training error of the combined classifier $H$ with respect to $D_1$ is bounded as

$$ Pr( H(x_i) \neq y_i) \leq \exp \left( -2 \sum_t \lambda_t^2 \right) $$

You can use this to show that, if your base (weak) classifiers have a fixed edge over being random (i.e. a small bias to being correct, no matter how small), then adaboost drives down the training error exponentially fast.  The proof of this inequality uses the relation (3) in a fundamental way.

I should note, there is nothing obvious about the algorithm.  I'm sure it took years and years of meditation and pots and pots of coffee to come into its final form - so there is nothing wrong with an initial ??? response to the setup.